# How do I check the contents in a vector using google-test?

Tags: c++, googletest

```
std::vector<uint8_t> vector1(10);
std::vector<uint8_t> vector2(10);

std::fill(vector1.begin(), vector1.end(), 2);
std::fill(vector2.begin(), vector2.end(), 2);

EXPECT_EQ(vector1, vector2);
```

Does the EXPECT_EQ() above check that the contents in vector1 and vector2 are equal? If not, how do I check that
that the contents in vector1 and vector2 are equal using a googletest EXPECT_* function?

The documentation for googletest explains how to test the contents of C strings and c++ string objects, but not how to check the contents of a c++ vector.

Comment: Did you check `if(vector1 == vector2) ...` ?

Comment: @Damien Sorry, I was not really clear of what I'm looking for, I'm only looking for ways to check that vector1 and vector2 are equal using googletest's EXPECT_*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`EXPECT_EQ` uses `operator ==` to compare objects, and [`operator ==` for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) (quote from cppreference):

> Checks if the contents of `lhs` and `rhs` are equal, that is, they have the same number of elements and each element in `lhs` compares equal with the element in `rhs` at the same position.

So the answer is **yes**, it will compare the contents of the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The googletest does explain how to compare containers (such as a vector) in the [matchers section](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#container-matchers).

The matcher `ContainerEq(container)` would probably do what you're after.
So something similar to `EXPECT_THAT(firstVector, testing::ContainerEq(secondVector));` might do the trick.